# What is the syntax for ffmpeg's -vf "split" option?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to learn how to use ffmpeg, and I came across this filtering example on http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FancyFilteringExamples. Specifically, this one:

`ffplay -f lavfi -i mandelbrot -vf "format=yuv444p,split=4\[a\]\[b\]\[c\]\[d\],\[a\]waveform\[aa\],\[b\]\[aa\]vstack\[V\],\[c\]waveform=m=0\[cc\],\[d\]vectorscope=color4\[dd\],\[cc\]\[dd\]vstack\[V2\],\[V\]\[V2\]hstack"`

This generates a mandelbrot fractal with two waveforms on either side, and a vectorscope in the bottom right corner. I want to apply this concept to a video I have, except with only the vectorscope and no waveforms. I've figured out how to generate the vectorscope as it's own file, but how can I specify it's l x w (pix) and then use the split syntax to add it to the bottom of the video?

So far, I've used

`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf vectorscope=color4 -f mp4 vectorscope.mp4`

to generate a 256x256 vectorscope of the original.

The way I understand the split syntax is that it is used in conjunction with the -vf option, something along the lines of:
`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf "format=h264, split=2[a][b],[a]vectorscope=color4 ... " -f mp4 output.mp4` but I'm not really sure what the syntax would be after that point.

Sorry if it seems like a silly question, I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

In the example below we take the first input `[0]` and split it to generate two instances `[S1]` and `[S2]`. We only need to state the number of instances if it is greater than two (i.e. `split=3`) .
We apply the vectorscope to one instance `[S1]` and output our vectorscope as
`[VS]`. This output is now overlaid onto the second instance `[S2]`. In this example we have overlaid in the top left corner (`overlay=0:0`), this can be adjusted to suit.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -vf ^
[0]split[S1][S2];^
[S1]vectorscope=color4[VS];^
[S2][VS]overlay=0:0 out.mp4
```

If we want to resize the vectorscope output before overlaying, we just scale its output `[VS]` prior to the overlay filter. We must now overlay the output from the scale filter `[VSS]`.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -vf ^
[0]split[S1][S2];^
[S1]vectorscope=color4[VS];^
[VS]scale=400:400[VSS];^
[S2][VSS]overlay=0:0 out.mp4
```

To take it one step further, we can crop the output from the vectorscope before rescaling. Here we scale by multiplying the input (*output from crop filter*) width (iw), and height (ih) by two (*2). This method is useful if the crop is not symmetrical.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -vf ^
[0]split[S1][S2];^
[S1]vectorscope=color4[VS];^
[VS]crop=100:100[CVS];^
[CVS]scale=2*iw:2*ih[VSS];^
[S2][VSS]overlay=0:0 out.mp4
```

Note: You can state the crop size **and position** (`50:25`) as follows:

```
crop=100:100:50:25
```

If you download the portable version of Avidemux, you can first generate your vectorscope, then open in Avidemux and use the crop filter to determine the values for ffmpeg. There is an auto crop option, but this should only be used as a starting point. Use the preview before noting values.

The values from the Avidemux filter correspond as follows:

Crop=**Width:Height:Left:Top** (Width & Height taken from Size). Left and Top represent x & y position.

https://www.avidemux.org/nightly/win64/